# Synonym for 'fundamentally upgrade/enhance'?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I would like to express that I fundamentally upgraded something in a concise way. That is, I did not create that something, but it is almost as if I completely redesigned it and made much better. The word would be used in the following way:

> I *fundamentally upgraded* the manufacturing process to allow for
>   considerably higher modularity and efficiency.

*'Improve'* or any of its synonyms are too weak, whereas *'fundamentally upgrade'* seems too clumsy to me.

I guess *'revamp'* is pretty close but it seems to me that this word might be too informal or not be appropriate in the given context.

Do you see any alternatives?

Comment: This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. wit221, single word requests as yours are required to provide an example sentence about the way the word will be used. Take the [tour] or have a look at the [help] to find out more about good questions.

Comment: Helmar, I edited my question to include an example sentence.

Comment: In a BBC TV interior design competition, the (horrible) word "upscaled" was frequently used by the judges.

Comment: @Ronald Sole, I too watched that programme and thought it was rather pretentious. Nevertheless, I would limit the word *up(-)scaled* to fashion or design.

Comment: Consider distinguishing, in your question, whether you *redesigned* the process or just *reimplemented* it. Has the basic design been changed, or just the way it is realized?

Comment: Your own term *redesigned* seems to fit, except that you say it's only "*almost* as if I completely redesigned it". In what way is it *almost* but not quite a redesign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to be honest, but also brag suitably about your accomplishment:

> I **overhauled** the manufacturing process.

"Take apart (a piece of machinery or equipment) in order to examine it and repair it if necessary.  Analyse and improve (a system)."

Example: "The steering box was recently overhauled."

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overhaul

Answer (score 1):

> I ***rebuilt*** the manufacturing process to allow for considerably
>   higher modularity and efficiency.

M-W:

> **rebuild**
>   *verb*
>
> : to make important improvements or changes in (something)